# persist/store object on click

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to send informations from a template to controller.

Here's the deal: I have 3 objects: flights, user, and reservation.

Each user can make any number of reservations, each reservation can include any number of flights.

Available flights are sent to me through an external API, and stored as an array.

When a user searches for a particular flight, I create a new reservation, and store it in session, along with displaying all of the available flights, with a twig for loop, as a package (let's say I want to fly from Paris to London, and then from London to Manchester, every availability will be sent as a package of 2 flights).

The packages are displayed using a simple twig loop.

```
{% for company in availabilities %}
    {% for pack in company %}
        <form action="{{ path('review') }}" method="post">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {% for l in pack %}
                        {% include ':flight:item.html.twig' with {'l' : l}%}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h3>No available flights.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

On every package, I would like to display a button than would take me to a review page, displaying every flight in the package.

The thing is, nothing is persisted: neither the flights, nor the reservation. Every call to the API returns a lot of availabilities, therefore, I do **not** want to persist anything.

to make it simple, is there a way, using form or routes, to send the package datas to my controller to be processed, even though nothing is persisted ?

Comment: does the external api not deliver an id ? e.g it does that for you

Comment: Well, the API does provide an ID, but it is set to be the ID of the plane company. Therefore, if several flights from the same company are available, this would mess things up. I was wondering if there was a way to send these datas without an actual key. Maybe I missed some of the SF2 documentation, or maybe it is just not possible in this way.